# Cannot install android-studio on Ubuntu - error 'unable to access sdk'

Tags: 14.04, android, android-studio, android-sdk

I have been trying to install android studio on Ubuntu 14.04 (64) and I have followed these steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

It installed so I found it using

```
dpkg -L android-studio
```

The application was installed in `/usr/share/applications/android-studio` which I physically clicked on from nautilus - which started the setup wizard. I clicked standard install.

It took a long time downloading the entire sdk but once it was fully downloaded it gave me this message:

```
Android SDK is up to date.
Creating Android virtual device
Unable to access SDK
```

And gave me just the option to finish which closed the setup wizard.

I tried the whole process again as root (`sudo nautilus` and again physically clicking on the application icon) and it downloaded the whole SDK a second time - and gave the same error!

I'm not sure if this is a Ubuntu problem, an Android Studio problem or just a me problem. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please review my edits and for the future, use 4 spaces or backticks "`" to improve readability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK it has been a lot of searching but it appears the problem is that the adb and some other sdk tools still use some 32bit libraries which have been deprecated and are no longer supplied with the latest version of Ubuntu 64....

Hopefully this issue will be resolved soon in the meantime I got it working with:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

And so far it is working as expected.

Hope this answer saves other people from spending a whole day searching for the problem :)

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me. Thanks for tracking this down.

Answer (score -1):

If also gives you issues regarding your open java version, please simply:

```
sudo apt-get update
```